# how to transefer menu varibale to menu semi-static page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

hi im new ruby on rails development currently im working with a reservation system to start learning but im currently having a problem with controllers and view

first i listed all the menu that the guest added inside the package that he also added i listed them with this

_menuadded.html.erb

```
<h1>menu you added</h1>
<% @reservation_package.package_line_items.each do |menu|%> 
<p><%= link_to menu.menu.name, menu_reservation_reservation_package_reservation_package_pages_path(@reservation,@reservation_package,menu) %></p>
<p><%= link_to "delete item" ,reservation_package_package_line_item_path(@reservation_package,menu), :method => :delete%></p>
<%end%>
```

then i try to route to the next static page with this `<p><%= link_to menu.menu.name, menu_reservation_reservation_package_reservation_package_pages_path(@reservation,@reservation_package,menu) %></p>`

and the it produce this URL `http://localhost:3000/reservations/10/reservation_packages/39/reservation_package_pages/menu.29`

im just wondering if how can i catch the menu that he opened i mean how to catch this **localhost:3000/reservations/10/reservation_packages/39/reservation_package_pages/`menu.29`**

in my menu semi static page controller where this route to,i tried this

```
@reservation_package = ReservationPackage.find(params[:reservation_package_id])
@menu = Menu.find(params[:id])
```

but didn't work at all im just wondering if im doing it right or if im wrong can you give me a advice how to implement this kind of module? thanks more power

**ROUTES:**

```
resources :services

   resources :reservations do

     resources :pages do
        collection do
          get :functionroomlist
          get :packagelist
          get :package
        #  get :menu
        end
     end
        resources :reservation_packages do
          resources :reservation_package_pages do
            collection do
               get :menulist 
               get :menu
            end
          end
        resources :package_line_items
        end
     resources :reservation_function_rooms        
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the url helper you are calling:

```
reservation_package_package_line_item_path
```

Then look at the routes you've defined:

```
    resources :reservation_packages do
      resources :reservation_package_pages do
        collection do
           get :menulist 
           get :menu
        end
      end
    resources :package_line_items
```

You've skipped over nested reservation_package_pages layer,  which is where you defined menu

You can tell something is wrong by the URL it generated,  with the DOT 29!

If it's working correctly, you'd have SLASH 29

do a

```
rake routes
```

And you should see the correct url helper to use to get to the menu route.

Comment: uhm reservation_package_package_line_item_path is working and cause i currently deleting the package of the reservation with `reservation_package_package_line_item_path` my issue is the `menu_reservation_reservation_package_reservation_package_pages_path(@reservation,@reservation_package,menu)` thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Yea,  damn your url helpers are rather long,  I'd recommend you eliminate the redundancy  in the naming,  it will make your life easier,  AND,  you have a very deeply nested design,  a good rule of thumb is that 2 levels of nesting is max,  if you find yourself deeper that 2 layers, best to rethink the design.  Your code is very difficult to read with both the deep nesting AND the redundancy in the level names.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply i solve my problem by changing this <p><%= link_to beer.beer.name, menu_reservation_reservation_package_reservation_package_pages_path(@reservatio‌​n,@reservation_package,menu) %></p> to this <p><%= link_to beer.beer.name, menu_reservation_reservation_package_reservation_package_pages_path(@reservatio‌​n,@reservation_package,:menu_id => menu.menu_id) %></p> im not sure if i did it right but i gives me what i wanted to which is to pass the beer id that was clicked and show its infromation